# What's the difference in using the internal formatting and using TEXT to format cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, formatting

What's the difference in using the *Formatting* drop-down and using `=text()` to format cells? Which one overrides the other or take priority? It seems I'm having some formatting conflict that is breaking my `=unique()` range and causing duplicates. Even though the rows looks the same, they are not de-duplicated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in essence, **`=TEXT()`** is superior over "drop-down" internal formatting because of higher priority:

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

[image: 5]

**note:** keep in mind that **`=TEXT()`** will convert the input into an actual chunk of text regardless of forcing numeric output with **`"0.0"`**. to convert it back you need to use **`=VALUE()`**

**note2:** on 3rd image you can see that internal formating overrode function formula, however, this is a purely visual issue eg. in a sense we could say that internal formatting is superior in terms of visual outputs - otherwise not.

Comment: Thank you! I have always been wondering what I should be putting in the 2nd param of Text() to force things to become "plain text". Turns out whatever I use it'll still be plain text?

I'm not quite sure if I understand the second part of Note2, do you mean that the drop-down only changes what is displayed, but not the actual value used for calculation? i.e. It can show 6decimal accuracy but uses only 2decimal to calculate if I used text("X", "0.00")?

Comment: @AllenSierra yes, "whatever" you use the final output is text, however, that "whatever" needs to be a valid mask (like dd, mmm, yyyy, #, 0, hh, mm, ss or even @). on behalf of your Note2 question... yes and no. yes for picture 3 but no for picture 1 - on which internal formatting "crippled" the actual value